# Synch a git remote partly to another

Tags: git

I have two remotes `one` and `two`. From time to time, the remote `two` gets new branches which are named in certain way, say `release/*`.

If there is a branch for instance `release/y` in `two`, but not in `one` I need to pull the "new" branches, but leave the "old" branches as they are.

So if there would be a branch `release/x` in `one`, but `release/y` and `release/z` are not, then will just add `y` and `z` from `two` to `one`.

I need to do it for 50+ projects, so I would like to have a universal solution here.

(I need to do the same for tags, by the way)

Are there any known ways?

Comment: Obviously there won't be a particular git command that exactly services this specific scenario, but it seems very easy to do with a script? List branches on "two" and aren't tracked locally, disregard those that are on "one", and for each remaining one pull it.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible (btw, how would iterate through the branches by script?). 2. I found this: `git push https://gitlab.com/dielok/repo1.git refs/remotes/zssi/*:refs/heads/*` and in a test-case it worked, because it skipped each branch on `one` which is non-fast-forward.